# php form with exec and sed commands

Tags: php, forms, sed, exec

I'm trying to create a php form to change values in a file on my vps. Here is the code I am trying:

```
<?php
echo "<form ";  
    $type = (int)$_POST['animal_type'];                  
    echo exec("sed -i 's/animal=*/animal=$type/g' /home/user1234/animals/file.props");
    echo "method='post'>";
    echo '<select name="animal_type" onChange="this.form.submit()">';
    echo '<option value="bat">bat</option>';
    echo '<option value="fish">fish</option>';
    echo '<option value="cat">cat</option>';
    echo '<option value="dog">dog</option>';
    echo '</select>';
 echo '</form>';
?>
```

I've updated my code again. Currently it just adds 00's to the animal= value in file.props instead of overwriting the current value with the value chosen in the form.

The value in the form on the php page also never changes and always stays as bat.

I also get this message every time I try to refresh the page: "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."

Is there a better method for changing these values other than sed and exec? Or am I still doing something incorrect in my code?

Comment: Is the sed command working directly from the cli?

Comment: user permission issue, always is when people try this

Comment: is `exec()` in the disabled_functions list in your php.ini?

Comment: Be careful on passing data directly to  the shell.  like `animal=$type`  Someone can post an animal_type with a single quote and execute shell commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [action attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action) of a form expects a URI to be specified. Instead, there is a [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function which returns a string. I'm assuming this string is not a valid URI. So in the source of the html it will look something like this:

```
<form action=some string returned by exec>
```

What is happening is the following:

1. The page is loaded
2. exec('sed....') is processed and the result is put in the html
3. User clicks submit and is taken to the URI specified in action. In this case it is the last line from the result of exec('sed....')

I recommend that you simplify this by changing the form to post to another page `<form action="changeFile.php">` then in changeFile.php add logic to modify the VPS file.

For example, in changeFile.php add logic to change the content with something like this:

```
<?php    
exec("sed -i 's/animal=*/animal=$_REQUEST['type']/g' /home/user1234/animals/file.props");
echo 'file modified'
?>
```

This could also be accomplished by having the page post to itself with something like the following:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

if(!empty($_REQUEST['animal_type'])){
    exec('sed -i '.escapeshellarg('s/animal=*/animal='.$_REQUEST['animal_type'].'/g')." /home/user1234/animals/file.props");
    echo 'File has been updated';
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="animal_type">;
        <option value="true">bat</option>;
        <option value="false">fish</option>;
        <option value="cat">cat</option>;
        <option value="dog">dog</option>;
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Bret! I'm making some progress now and updated my post.

Comment: I've added a few notes to hopefully make this more clear. The point is you want exec() to run on the second page post_test.php. Otherwise, exec() is running at the time the page is first loaded and before the user has had a chance to specify the animal_type.

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess my original code was off as I wouldn't like them to be redirected to a page after the change is made. I've updated my code again in the original post. My brain is a bit confused currently so I better take 5mins :)

Comment: Thanks again :) That appears to work great. The only issue I have now is the "animal=cat" value in the file doesn't get changed but the form just adds on to it so after a few tried I get: "animal=catdogdog". I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Your regex needs changed from `s/animal=*/` to `s/animal=.*/`. The * means: `Matches zero or more occurrences of the previous character`  and . means `any character`. So `.*` means any character zero or more times. `=*` means `equal sign zero or more times`.

Comment: Got it :) Guess I was a bit over my head here! One last question: Is it possible to make it so the form "remembers" the value that you have changed? IE: When I change the value on the web form, it always reverts to the first value, in this case "bat". Is there anyway to get it to match the value that it has been changed to in the file.props file? Even if you refreshed the page or left it? Again can't say thanks enough!

Comment: Yes, you will need to first retrieve the value from the file.props. You could use something like grep or [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) to retrieve the value. Then you will need to set the option tag to selected for the specific item with something like `<option value="cat" selected="selected"></option>`. I suggest you start another question if you need more details or keep searching Google there should be lots of examples out there.

Comment: Okay will do Brett and thanks again your help was greatly appreciated! I learned more than excepted over something I thought would be very simple.